# I'm creating a code to greet me based on time of day and for some reason it can't distinguish my name from other text

Tags: javascript, function

I'm coding a simple script that greets based on time of day when I typing my own name into the prompt and will give a message stating otherwise if it's not me.

```
var name= prompt("What is your name?");
    var clock = new Date();
    var time = clock.getHours();

    if (name = "Mayo"){
    if (time < 10) {
  greeting = "Good morning" + " " + name + ".";
} else if (time < 20) {
  greeting = "Good day" + " " + name + ".";
} else {
  greeting = "Good evening" + " " + name + ".";
}

document.write(greeting)

 }

else {
    wrongName = "You are not" + " " + name + "."
    document.write(wrongName)
}
```

It seems to work timewise so far but can't distinguish my name from that of other text and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

On line 5 `if (name = "Mayo"){`, one `=` is the assignment operator. For comparison, try using `==` for loose equality (in case the prompt comes in as a type other than a string like `['Mayo']`) or `===` for strict equality if you require it to be a string. Otherwise, the engine will interpret `name = "Mayo"` as you are trying to assign "Mayo" to the variable `name`.

**Summary:** Change line 5 to `if (name == "Mayo") {` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Shit. I forgot about that. Well, I'm retarded, lol thanks! :)